# Confusion about the Key in the Key Ring

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, encryption-symmetric, data-protection

I am using **ASP.NET Core Data Protection** for my data protection.
I got below error while unprotecting the data using decrypt method.

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {e47ceea6-be1f-440b-b204-64ff5a152552} was not found in the key ring.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
```

I went through this documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-management?view=aspnetcore-2.1#automatic-key-ring-refresh

So the key referred in the exception above is the same KeyId you get on keyManager.GetAllKeys() result?

Code sample from documentation -

```
// list all keys in the key ring 
var allKeys = keyManager.GetAllKeys(); 
 Console.WriteLine($"The key ring contains {allKeys.Count} key(s).");
 foreach (var key in allKeys) {
 Console.WriteLine($"Key {key.KeyId:B}: Created = {key.CreationDate:u},IsRevoked = {key.IsRevoked}"); 
}
```